# Scrape JS site with NodeJS, Nightmare and Cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to scrape a website to get the scores of each team.  I am running into an issue where my script is returning null content.  I cannot see where I am going wrong and looking for some help.

JS:

```js
const Nightmare = require('nightmare')
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs');


const nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true })
const url = 'https://www.mscl.org/live/scorecard/ed7941919f69b0e11e800fef/mHcehsPR9S86T3zQv';

nightmare
  .goto(url)
  .wait('body')
  .wait('div#summaryTab.tab-pane.fade.in.table-responsive.borderless.active')
  .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('div.col-md-6').innerHTML)
  .end()
  .then(response => {
    console.log(getData(response));
  }).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
  });

  let getData = html => {
    data = [];
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('div').each((i, elem) => {
        if(i === 0 ){
          console.log($(elem).find('nth-child(1)').html());
          
        }
    });
    return data;

  }
```

The html I am scraping is here.
https://pastebin.com/R6syWDwD

The line where the scores are: 30 and 32

```html
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <b>40 Overs Match</b><br>
        <b>MVCC Combined</b> won the toss and chose Batting<br>
        <b>Umpires: </b>No umpires were selected<br>
        <b>Date: </b> 3/24/2021, 5:00:00 PM<br>
        <b>Ground: </b>Acton Field 1<br>
        <b>Result: TBD</b><br>
        <b>MoM: </b> <br>
        <hr>
        
        <p><b>MVCC COMBINED XI - 147/10</b> (<b>O:</b> 12.5 | <b>RR:</b> 11.45)</p>
        
        <p><b>MVCC United XI - 23/1</b> (<b>O:</b> 2.0 | <b>RR:</b> 11.50)</p>
        <hr>
      </div>
```

When I run this it returns nothing.  No errors are being displayed either.  What am i missing?

Answer (score 0):

The [jQuery Docs for nth-child](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) says

> jQuery's implementation of :nth- selectors is strictly derived from the CSS specification

So you propably have to provide an element to your `nth-child(1)`-pseudo-selector, to tell jQuery from which element it should select the nth-child of. try this:

```
console.log($(elem).find('b:nth-child(1)').html());
```

alternatively, just try to prefix `nth-child(1)` with a colon -> `:nth-child(1)`

**Edit:**

I just realized you are using innerHTML on your selected div, which actually returns the contents of the div without the wrapping div itself. But in `getData` you try to select the div with `$('div')` which then is actually not found.